# In app purchase using parse.com SDK

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, parse-platform

I am utilizing the parse.com sdk for a number of things in my app, so I thought I would also piggyback on it for my in app purchase.  I have an alert view with an "Upgrade" button that calls the following block.  I have verified that the block is being called but I am not able to get to the completion block.  Has anyone else encountered this?

```
if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Upgrade"])
{
    [PFPurchase buyProduct:@"com.mysite.myapp.fullversionupgrade" block:^(NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            UIAlertView *succesfulUpgradeAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Upgrade Complete" message:@"Thank you for upgrading." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [succesfulUpgradeAlert show];
        }
    }];
}
```

I should also point out that this app is not yet up and running on the app store, and I just added the in app purchase information today.  Does that make a difference? I understand those can be factors, but my alert view is simply being dismissed and, again, I'm not even getting to the completion block.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your question:

> my alert view is simply being dismissed and, again, I'm not even
>   getting to the completion block.

Does that mean you are getting an alert? If that is the case, doesn't that mean that your completion block is being called?

I am using the same exact code in production right now, and it works. If you want to try In App Purchase, try it on your device and create a test account in iTunes Connect. Don't rely on the simulator for this, I have mixed results with the simulator.

Comment: Sorry, I can see how my question was confusing. The code I pasted above is run after selecting "upgrade" from and alert view. That is the alert view that is being dismissed. The alert view you can see into completion block is never called.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint on the if statement and NSLog the error value? I really don't see anything wrong with your code, I am using exactly the same code.

Comment: Great suggestion.  Here is the error I am getting:

Error = Error Domain=Parse Code=146 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Parse error 146.)"

After doing some research it looks like it simply isn't able to verify with the app store that the ID is correct.  Now this is my first app, the app is not live, and the IAP obviously has not been approved yet.  Do I need to submit the app, along with the IAP, and then test it?  Once I submit it . . . if I have to change anything will I have to resubmit it?  I feel like this is a chicken and the egg problem.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have IAP of `com.mysite.myapp.fullversionupgrade` in iTunes Connect? You need to create it first. Then test it in a device, not simulator. Don't submit it if it's not working yet.